# Mysql query to return result from mapping table in order of occurence

Tags: mysql

I have one table A_B mapping. Now I want those A which are associated with single B only.

```
A    B
12  16
12  22
12  23
12  26
23  16
24  26
```

Suppose if I will search for A whose are associated with B = 16, I will get 12 and 23 A.
But I want only 23 as it is only associated with B=16.

Second choice can be first 23 then 12 will occur.
So first priority will be to single association items, then multiple associations will occur.

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
select A
  from test4 T1
 where B=16
   and not exists(select 1 from test4 T2
                   where T2.A=T1.A and T2.B<>T1.B)
```

2.

```
select A 
  from test4 T1
 where B=16
 order by exists(select 1 from test4 T2
                  where T2.A=T1.A and T2.B<>T1.B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this ?

```
Select A FROM A_B where B IN (Select B FROM A_B where A=12) and A<>'12'
```